# What are some reputable merchant account providers for high risk payment web sites?

Tags: payments, payment-gateway

I am helping to set up an online cigar web site.  However, it has become a real pain to take payments online since tobacco is considered a "high-risk" item and nobody will provide a merchant account to process the payments.  It looks like there are companies that specialize in high-risk merchant accounts.  I was wondering if anybody could recommend a high-risk merchant account and payment processing provider?

Comment: Have you talked to your bank about opening a merchant account with them?

Comment: Has your question been answered or do you need more information?

Comment: +1 - This has been an ongoing nightmare for the gun store I'm trying to get online. I've spoken with a bunch of merchant account providers and they're all eager to help until they find out what we want to sell online. Our provider for the brick and mortar store finally agreed to do it as long as we made certain changes, but now that we're ready to go, they're saying they can't help us. Frustrating. Of course, there's always PayPal - meh.

Comment: @boot13 try http://www.durango-direct.com/ you can get a real merchant account with them setup through authorize.net etc as a high risk retailer.

Answer (score 1):

try alert pay, moneybookers, bluepay, or digital gold currency

Answer (score 1):

http://www.usfsg.com/ might be able to help you. I am not affiliated with them but I know they are serious when it comes to offshore and high rish merchant accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [TrustWho](http://www.trustwho.com/business.php) to vet the authenticity of buyers. They reduce fraud significantly.